# laravel eloquent, many to many, custom column names, what am I doing wrong

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
menuitem:
    Id int
    MenuLevel int
    Label varchar(50)
    Controller varchar(50)
    Action varchar(50)
    ParentId int

role:
    Id int
    Name varchar(50)

menurole:
    MenuRoleId int (primary key)
    RoleId int (foreign key to Role)
    MenuItemId int (foreign key to MenuItem)
```

I am trying to retrieve all menu items and to display them in a table, and to display all the roles that each menu item has as a comma separated list in a single table cell.

My models:

```
class MenuItem extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'menuitem';  
    public $timestamps = false; 

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'menurole', 'MenuItemId', 'RoleId');
    }
}

class Role extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'role';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function menuItems()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('MenuItem', 'menurole', 'RoleId', 'MenuItemId');
    }
}
```

Code that prepares the data for the view in controller looks like this:

```
$menuItems = MenuItem::all();
```

All that is done in the view is double foreach loop. One to get all menu items, and the other one to get all the roles for every menu item.

```
@foreach ($menuItems as $item)
    @foreach ($item->roles as $role)
        <span>{{ $role->Name }}</span>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The problem is that there are no roles retrieved. Menu items are there. Renaming db columns is not an option for now. **What am I doing wrong ?**

EDIT:
Running on WAMP, MySql version 5.6.12

Comment: You get any error? $item->roles is null or what is going on there?

Comment: Here's the var_dump on the one of the menu items roles collection:
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#171 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: Meaning the relationship is loaded, but there's no data. Use $menuItems->all()->load('roles'); then dd(DB::getQueryLog()); it will show you 2 queries that were run (1st for retrieving items and 2nd for roles) this way you can check on the db is you do have related data.

Comment: second query:
select `role`.*, `menurole`.`MenuItemId` as `pivot_MenuItemId`, `menurole`.`RoleId` as `pivot_RoleId` from `role` inner join `menurole` on `role`.`id` = `menurole`.`RoleId` where `menurole`.`MenuItemId` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Although it selected menu items in the first query, it failed to fetch MenuItemID's in the second query

Comment: Did you try `$this->belongsToMany('Role', 'menurole', 'RoleId', 'MenuItemId')`?

Comment: I've tried swapping parameter places but it then loses track of relation and tries to inner join roleId with menuitemID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem would be properly setting your primary keys in your models..

Each model needs this with relevant key name.

```
public $primaryKey = 'primarykeyname'
```

Additionally, appropriate way to eagler load would be to use it like so...

```
$menuItems = MenuItem::with('role')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

try loading the relations with [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading).

```
$menuItems = MenuItem::with('role')->get();
```

Comment: got: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with()
I'll look at the link right now, thanks

Comment: It would be just `$menuItems = MenuItem::with('role')->get();`.  Additionally, you need to set your primary keys in your model as well.  Add `public $primaryKey = 'primarykeyname'` with the appropriate primary key name to each model.

Comment: @user3158900 Please convert comment to answer or something so I can accept it. That did it. Thank you very much.